# Secure Login with MVC with a database/entity first

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to use the MVC IUA template to connect my database (with pre-existing usernames and passwords) and log in using the credentials in that database.

What I want to ask is, is it possible to have a secure login (OWIN, Cookies, salt and hashed passwords) with the database I have without using the MVC template registration for username/passwords?

I've been looking around SO, blogs like James Surtevant/Bem Foster, Microsoft's documentation for answers without much success. (And honestly this might be above my skill level and comprehension for now)

I think at this point, I'm starting to understand that it might not be possible? I don't want to use the database the registration creates for you but I ***do*** want to use  the security protocols the template has but for my logins. But it seems you can't do that without registering first… Am I right? I feel like I'm trying to reinvent the wheel with all this.

Comment: Not sure what you trying to do, if I understood correctly you want to use asp.net identity with your existing database which doesn't have tables like `AspNetUsers` etc? If so you would have to create your own Custom Storage Provider. This [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity) should help you get started.

Comment: @penleychan I'm not sure what I'm trying to do either honestly, but your link was a big help in giving me a **a lot** more direction! Thank you penleychan.